# Merge Target Column back to the original dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe and I did some features selection (following a guide) to drop some columns:

**What I did:**

```
X = df.drop('goal', axis=1).select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
y = df['goal']
```

Then I selected columns using mutual_info_gain:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression, mutual_info_classif
info_gain = mutual_info_classif(X, y)
```

And finally:

```
columns_to_keep = []
for score, f_name in sorted(zip(info_gain, X.columns), reverse=True)[:50]:
        print(f_name, score)


        columns_to_keep.append(f_name)
df_info_gain = X[columns_to_keep]
```

So now `df_info_gain` has all 50 features I selected but not the `goal` column `y`

**What I need:**

What's the correct way to bring back the `goal` column to this new `df_info_gain` dataframe?

Comment: If the index hasn't changed, you could try `df_info_gain = df_info_gain.merge(y.to_frame(name="goal"), left_index=True, right_index=True)`.

Comment: `df_info_gain = df_info_gain.assign(goal=y)`